# Can't store a korean string in database using LINQ

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I'm using this code to store korean string in my database:

```
Dim username As String = Request.QueryString.Get("Some Korean String")
Using dg As New DataContext()
Dim newfriend As New FriendsTable With {.AskingUser = User.Identity.Name, .BeingAskedUser = username, .Pending = True}
dg.FriendsTables.InsertOnSubmit(newfriend)
dg.SubmitChanges()
end using
```

Checking my database, the username stored is a string"????"...
anybody got an idea how this happened or any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are storing Korean text in a varchar/text column which is not using a Korean collation. Thea easiest fix is to change the column type to nvarchar/ntext.

The [nchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) column types store Unicode data, whereas the [char and varchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) types store single byte characters in the specified collation.

Answer (score 1):

What is your database collation? Are you able to store Korean strings with any other data access technology? What is the type of the username column, and is it accurately mapped in LINQ to SQL?

I suspect that *something* in the database isn't set up correctly to allow full Unicode. I very much doubt that this has anything to do with LINQ itself.

The other thing to check is that you're actually getting the right data in the first place. There are often several places where things can go wrong - you need to validate each place separately to see where the data is being corrupted. I have a [short article on this](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/debuggingunicode.html) which you may find helpful.

Comment: .beingaskeduser column is in varchar...and the code is working on alpanumeric string but when I get a korean string, this happens